# self loop edges too short and ugly in graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I drawed a picture using graphviz. Please see  [FSM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsVUW.png).
I think It is ugly because self loop edges are so short.
The attribute "minlen" of edges  doesn't work for me.
And I tried several ports of the node, but it all shows a mess except my current implementation. Do you have a clever idea for me ?
Code is here:

```
digraph finite_state_machine {
rankdir=LR;
size="8,2"
fontname="Verdana"
node [shape = doublecircle]; Idle;
node [shape = circle,nodesep = "2.0"];
Working:s -> Working:s [ label = "response[j]?" ,minlen = 50000];
Idle -> Working [ label = "boot" ];
Working:n -> Working:n [ label = "sendtx[i]!",minlen = 50000 ];
Working:e -> Working:e [ label = "qry!" ,minlen = 50000];
```

}

Comment: what's more font attribute does not work for me . I use graphviz in windows. And I have tried to modify  /etc/fonts/fonts.conf as :<dir>C:/Windows/Fonts</dir>

Answer (score 1):

Adding `nodesep=1;` makes loops larger, although not nicer. So this would help:

```
digraph finite_state_machine {
  rankdir=LR;
  size="8,2"
  fontname="Verdana"
  node [shape = doublecircle]; Idle;
  node [shape = circle,nodesep = "2.0"];
  Working:s -> Working:s [ label = "response[j]?" ,minlen = 50000];
  Idle -> Working [ label = "boot" ];
  Working:n -> Working:n [ label = "sendtx[i]!" ];
  Working:e -> Working:e [ label = "qry!"];
  nodesep=1;
}
```

Will produce something like:

[Dot Output](http://www.gravizo.com/svg?digraph%20finite_state_machine%20%7B%20%20rankdir=LR;%20%20size=%228,2%22%20%20fontname=%22Verdana%22%20%20node%20[shape%20=%20doublecircle];%20Idle;%20%20node%20[shape%20=%20circle,nodesep%20=%20%222.0%22];%20%20Working:s%20-%3E%20Working:s%20[%20label%20=%20%22response[j]?%22%20,minlen%20=%2050000];%20%20Idle%20-%3E%20Working%20[%20label%20=%20%22boot%22%20];%20%20Working:n%20-%3E%20Working:n%20[%20label%20=%20%22sendtx[i]%22];%20%20Working:e%20-%3E%20Working:e%20[%20label%20=%20%22qry%22%20];%20%20nodesep=0.7;%7D)