# Graphviz: Loop to the left should have the same shape as loop to the right

Tags: graphviz

Consider this small graph:

```
digraph G {
    {rank = same; node12; node11;}

    node11 [ label = "node left", shape=square ]
    node11 -> node11 [label=" i[2,9]"]
    node11 -> node12 [label=" k[2]"]
    node12 [ label = "node right", shape=square ]
    node12 -> node12 [label=" i[9]"]
}
```

I converted it to pdf with `dot -Tpdf`

```
$ dot -V
dot - graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304)
```

[image]

As you can see the (self-)loop of the left node and the edge connecting the left and right node overlap. I was trying to fix this by using the [compass](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k:portPos) functionality of graphviz. My first try was: `node11:w -> node11:w [label=" i[2,9]"]`:

[image]

However, the resulting shape of the loop has changed. I do not want this and I agree that it looks [uglier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48155198/self-loop-edges-too-short-and-ugly-in-graphviz). Increasing `nodesep=1;` does not give you the same shape as the right one. Of course you can make the right loop identical to the left loop by  adding `:e`. But I prefer the shape of the original right loop.

Are there any other possibilities to achieve this?

BTW: Mathematica graph drawing is cleverer here: it automatically places the self loop to the other side. But IMHO needs a lot of customization to get a neutral style:

```
Graph[{1 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 2}, 
 EdgeLabels -> {(1 -> 1) -> "i[2,9]", (1 -> 2) -> "k[2]", (2 -> 2) -> 
    "i[9]"}, EdgeLabelStyle -> Directive[15, Background -> White], 
 VertexSize -> 0.3, VertexShapeFunction -> "Rectangle", 
 VertexStyle -> White, EdgeStyle -> Black, 
 VertexLabels -> {1 -> Placed["node left", Center], 
   2 -> Placed["node right", Center]}]
```

[image]

And just to be clear: this is only a fragment of the graph. The final graph looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it somewhat like this:

```
digraph G {

  node[margin=0 _color=invis shape=none height=.2
  label=<<table BORDER="1" CELLBORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0">
    <tr>
        <td port="a1"></td>
        <td port="b1"></td>
        <td port="c1"></td>
        <td port="d1"></td>
        <td port="e1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td port="a2"></td>
        <td rowspan="3" colspan="3">
        \N
        </td>
        <td port="e2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td port="a3"></td>
        <td port="e3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td port="a4"></td>
        <td port="e4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td port="a5"></td>
        <td port="b5"></td>
        <td port="c5"></td>
        <td port="d5"></td>
        <td port="e5"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>>]

  x:a2:w->x:a4:w
  x:e2:e->x:e4:e
  x->y
  y:a2:w->y:a4:w
}
```

rendered by viz-js.com:
[image: rendered by viz-js.com]